# How to remove a collect into a new stream from the middle of a java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm working on a Java 8 stream. And I need group by 2 keys in a map. And then put these keys with their value into a new function.

Is there a way to skip the `Collector` and reading it out again?

```
graphs.stream()
    .map(AbstractBaseGraph::edgeSet)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        graph::getEdgeSource,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            graph::getEdgeTarget,
            Collectors.counting()
        )
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(startEntry ->
        startEntry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(endEntry ->
                graph.setEdgeWeight(
                    graph.addEdge(startEntry.getKey(), endEntry.getKey()),
                    endEntry.getValue() / strains
                )));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to have some sort of an intermediate data structure to accumulate counts.  Depending on how your graph and edge classes are written, you could try to accumulate counts directly into the graph, but that would be less readable and more brittle.

Note that you can iterate over the intermediate map more concisely by using [`Map#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
.forEach((source, targetToCount) -> 
    targetToCount.forEach((target, count) -> 
        graph.setEdgeWeight(graph.addEdge(source, target), count/strains)
    )
);
```

You can also collect the counts into `Map<List<Node>, Long>` instead of `Map<Node,Map<Node,Long>>` if you dislike the map-of-maps approach:

```
graphs.stream()
    .map(AbstractBaseGraph::edgeSet)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(groupingBy(
            edge -> Arrays.asList(
                graph.getEdgeSource(edge), 
                graph.getEdgeTarget(edge)
            ),
            counting()
    ))
    .forEach((nodes, count) -> 
        graph.setEdgeWeight(graph.addEdge(nodes.get(0), nodes.get(1)), count/strains)
    );
```

Comment: *"you have to have some sort of an intermediate data structure to accumulate counts"*, unless the input is already sorted or can be traversed in a grouped manner allowing you to emit one group at a time as stream element.

Comment: Yes, some sources may allow a way to directly compute counts just as some targets may allow to directly accumulate them, but that's not what OP is asking about.